Installed Windows Admin center:
I downloaded and installed windows admin center on my computer and I have not been able to use my system as before. It keeps telling me that it cannot connect to my windows account so everything I do on the computer is only temporarily saved. Please how can I recover the former state of my system? Thank you.
I've uninstalled the Windows Admin center and tried to clear out the cache. I've also tried to login to my One drive several times but I keep receiving error messages and that I can't be logged in.
